# What are those numbers in gdb?

Tags: gdb

I disassemble my C code (just printf("hello world") ) in gdb and I got

```
0x0000000000001135 <+0>: push rbp 
0x0000000000001136 <+1>: mov rbp,rsp
0x0000000000001139 <+4>: lea rdi [rip+0xec4] # 0x2004
0x0000000000001140 <+11>: mov eax,0x0
0x0000000000001145 <+16>: call 0x1030 <printf@plt>
0x000000000000114a <+21>: mov eax,0x0 
0x000000000000114f <+26>: pop rbp
0x0000000000001150 <+27>: ret
```

I set break point to main and exam rip register.

```
rip            0x555555555139   0x555555555139 <main+4>
```

What are those numbers in font of < > in gdb?
I can only access the memory that rip point to.

if those numbers aren't memories can I change format that make gdb display memory?

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What are those numbers in font of < > in gdb? I can only access the memory that rip point to.

You are dealing with a [position independent executable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code#PIE), which is linked to load at address `0`, but is *relocated at runtime* to a different address (in your case, `0x555555554000`).

You likely performed `disas` *before* running the application (i.e. before the relocation happened). If instead you do this:

```
(gdb) start
(gdb) disas main
```

then GDB will show you relocated instructions.